# display two columns side by side javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

Hi I am trying to display the data from an array to a html output table.But the thing is I need to display the table on the same page after selecting submit button.If I am using document.write it is going to another page.Also by using document.write I am unable to display two columns side by side.

```
   document.write("<table>");
    document.write('<tr><th>First Name</th></tr>');

    for(var h = 0; h< data.length;h++){
        document.write('<tr><td>' + data[h] + '</td></tr>');

    }
            document.write('</table>');
```

The above code displays first table.

```
  document.write("<table>");
    document.write('<tr><th>Last Name</th></tr>');

    for(var g = 0; g< data.length;g++){
        document.write('<tr><td>' + data1[g] + '</td></tr>');

    }
            document.write('</table>');
```

The above code gives me second column but it is not displaying beside the first. FYI, I am getting the data from localstorage and storing it an array.Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why can't you try like this?**

```
document.write("<table>");
document.write('<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>');
  for(var h = 0; h< data.length;h++){
    document.write('<tr><td>' + data[h] + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + data1[h] + '</td></tr>');
  }
document.write('</table>');
```

> Because both the for loops looping data only

Then it will shows like

```
First Name | Last Name
----------------------
firstName1 | lastName1
firstName2 | laseName2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot praveen.It worked.So stupid of me to write two tables.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry my bad Naveen.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Tables are block elements and will be on a new line. If you want them next to each other use float for example.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

    .tableData {
        float: left;
    }

</style>
```

Script

```
document.write("<table class='tableData'>");
    document.write('<tr><th>First Name</th></tr>');

    for(var h = 0; h< data.length;h++){
        document.write('<tr><td>' + data[h] + '</td></tr>');

    }
            document.write('</table>');


  document.write("<table class='tableData'>");
    document.write('<tr><th>Last Name</th></tr>');

    for(var g = 0; g< data.length;g++){
        document.write('<tr><td>' + data1[g] + '</td></tr>');

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mouser for the help.

Comment: No problem, this fixes your question, the answer from @Naveen helps you write (and understand) coding in JavaScript better.